# Программа для анализа шаблонов C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, инструменты-разработчика

Существует ли программа\инструмент, который по коду, в котором написан шаблон, определяет, как должен выглядеть класс `T`, который используется как параметр шаблона:

- Какие у него должны быть методы.
- Какие должны быть определены функции с ним.
- Какие поля у него должны быть.
- и т.д.

Либо же говорит, что если подставить вместо `T` какие-то классы, которые определены в коде, то он скомпилируется.

*Пример:*

Имеется такой шаблон функции:

```
template<class T> 
void foo(T a)
{
    T b = a;
    boo(a, 1);
    b = a - b;
    a.foo2(b);
    b.param = a.param;
    T::foo1(b);
}
```

Анализируя этот код, программа говорит, что класс `T` должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
class T
{
public:
    T();
    ~T();

    T(T&);

    T operator-(T& b);
    static void foo1(T);
    void foo2(T);

    UNKNOWN_TYPE param;
}
```

И для него должны быть перегружены такие функции:

```
void boo(T, INT_TYPE);
```

С какими параметрами он скомпилируется:

```
Функция foo скомпилируется, если в качестве параметра T использовать классы: 
Class1, Class2, Class3<double>, Class3<float>.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, это невозможно. Для решения этой проблемы вы (кроме полного парсера C++) должны решить алгоритмическую [проблему останова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), так как шаблоны в C++ полны по Тьюрингу. А значит, определить, скомпилируется данная подстановка или нет, равносильно тому, чтобы определить, завершится произвольный алгоритм или нет.

Вот вам небольшой [де]мотивирующий пример. Определим вспомогательный шаблон, который умеет вычислять степень числа во время компиляции:

```
template <unsigned int x, unsigned int n>
struct static_power
{
    enum { value = static_power<x, n - 1>::value * x };
};

template <unsigned int x>
struct static_power<x, 0>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Рассмотрим теперь вот такой шаблон:

```
template<unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z, unsigned int n>
struct Fermat
{
    static_assert(n > 2, "Wrong power");
    static_assert(static_power<x, n>::value + static_power<y, n>::value ==
                       static_power<z, n>::value, "Fermat proof");
};
```

Этот шаблон можно инстанциировать только с теми числами `x`, `y`, `z`, `n`, которые являются решением Великой теоремы Ферма.

Как вы думаете, легко ли написать программу, которая сможет автоматически доказать теорему Ферма?

---

**Примечание**. Проблема здесь не только в числовых параметрах. Шаблон можно переписать и так:

```
template<typename X, typename Y, typename Z, typename N>
struct Fermat
{
    static_assert(N::value > 2, "Wrong power");
    static_assert(
        static_power<X::value, N::value>::value +
        static_power<Y::value, N::value>::value ==
        static_power<Z::value, N::value>::value,
        "Fermat proof");
};
```

---

P. S.: Решить задачу простым перебором классов не получится, т. к. шаблоны приносят в программу по существу *бесконечное* множество классов.

Например, имея

```
template<typename T> struct X { /**/ };
```

мы определяем сразу `X<void>`, `X<X<void>>`, `X<X<X<void>>>` и т. д.

Comment: Это ну очень частный случай. Вопрос состоял не в том, возможно ли такое алгоритмически, и не в том, какие есть нюансы, а в том, есть ли инструмент. Даже самый примитивный. Как минимум простейшая задача - какие классы подходят в качестве параметра шаблона. Это решается перебором всех имеющихся классов и типов в коде и вывод того, с чем компилируется. Но ваш пример тоже хорош. Это показывает, что такая программа не сможет определять подходящие числовые параметры(а может и не надо вовсе). Я думаю что за все время существования C++ должны были написать хоть что-нибудь подобное.

Comment: @zorax: Это **простой** частный случай. Сложность вашей проблемы настолько велика, что инструмент, работающий для сколько-нибудь нетривиальных шаблонов, невозможен. Поэтому его никто не написал, и более того, никогда не напишет.

Comment: убедили, слишком сложно сделать инструмент, который делает первую часть того, что я написал, даже ограниченный. Но ведь есть и вторая часть вопроса: **перебор всех имеющихся типов в программе, и проверка, подходят ли они как параметр шаблона**. Конечно, тут можно создавать бесконечное число типов при помощи шаблонов, проверка которых не кончится никогда. **Но это можно ограничить.** Уже такой инструмент не настолько сложно написать, и возможно, что подобное кто-то писал.

Comment: Ладно, наверное все-таки не существует ничего подобного, потому что вы бы о нем знали. Спасибо. Отсутствие возможности такого анализа, или инструмента - существенное неудобство. Было бы очень удобно генерировать такую информацию для документации при помощи такого инструмента для больших проектов, использующих много шаблонов. А так, в документации остается только вручную дописывать, что подходит в параметре шаблона, а что нет.

Comment: @zorax: Тут непонятно, как ограничивать. Потому что всего-навсего `std::string` — это, по существу, `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`, а уж `std::vector<std::string>` чем является, можно представить себе. То есть даже для нормальных, привычных случаев _глубина быстро становится огромной_.

Comment: @VladD мне кажется что топик стартер просто хотел получить список методов для класса, инстанцирующего шаблон. С такой задачей вполне справляется транслятор С++, когда пишет нам сообщение об ошибке вида "отсутствует метод ХХХ у класса YYY". Не очень понятно, зачем коллеге нужен такой инструмент, если транслятор и есть такой инструмент. И при трансляции ему честно скажут где и какой метод он забыл определить. Часто и не нужно определять все методы инстанцирующего класса, если они используются в неиспользуемых здесь и сейчас методах шаблона.

Comment: @VladD что касается примера с теоремой Ферма, то в нем для инстанцирования шаблона подойдет любое целое со всеми его методами сложением, вычитанием и т.д. А то, что алгоритм не закончится, это уже не вопрос инструмента, который ищет топик стартер, это вопрос собственно алгоритма. Вобщем мне кажется, что такой инструмент, который анализирует все методы, которые применяются к класс-параметру шаблона в методах шаблона вполне может быть создан на базе транслятора С++.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Не-а, так не сработает. Потому что шаблон может вполне скармливать тип другому шаблону (и большинство таки делают, например, `vector<T>` скармливает `T` шаблону аллокатора. То есть у нас началась уже сложность. А дальше больше.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Ну инструмент не просто «не закончится». В шаблонах вполне можно организовать бесконечный цикл (`template<typename T> struct X { X<X<T>> field; }`) — вот и анализатор завис.

Answer (score 7):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос спустя 3 года, потому что нашёл решение лучше.

Для начала надо понимать, что на самом деле в шаблонах C++ утиная типизация. Утиная мета-типизация на этапе компиляции. Если ваш объект обладает нужными полями и нужными методами, то он подходит и компилируется.

Проблема этого подхода в том же, в чём проблема языка с утиной типизацией обычных объектов: сложно отследить требования к объекту только по сигнатуре функции, нужно заглядывать в её код или молиться что это сказано в документации, а если при использовании происходит ошибка, то она происходит где-то внутри сложного кода.

Поэтому и анализ требований к классу такой же сложный как автоматический вывод типов в Python или JS. Хотя, наверное, с шаблонной магией, C++ оказывается куда сложнее в анализе, о чём и писал VladD.

Решение здесь примерно такое же, как и решение с утиной типизацией: **ввести типы**, которые программист должен писать сам. Но в данном случае это будет типизация типов.

В C++, насколько мне известно, этим занимаются Концепты, которые обещают в C++20. В C# тоже есть подобное через интерфейсы. Проблема в них только в том, что для обратной совместимости они не будут обязательны при написании шаблонного кода. И в старых библиотеках вы всё-равно не разберётесь так просто (я изначально задавал этот вопрос, пытаясь разобраться с библиотекой Anti-Grain Geometry).

А ещё есть язык Rust, где данная проблема решена изначально, и там нельзя использовать метод у объекта, если это не специфицировано в сигнатуре функции. Например:

```rust
trait Fooable {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> i32;
}

fn print_foo_five_times<T: Fooable>(t: &mut T) {
    for _ in 0..5 {
        println!("{}", t.foo());
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Bar {
    counter: i32,
}

impl Fooable for Bar {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> i32 {
        self.counter += 1;
        self.counter
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar::default();
    print_foo_five_times(&mut bar);
}
```

[Ссылка на онлайн-компилятор.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12c73b86f9ca6bc807fda9b2a0aa99ec)

В данном коде имеется шаблонная функция `print_foo_five_times`, которая вызывает метод  `foo` у переданного объекта. При этом чтобы вызвать этот метод, надо в сигнатуре описать, что тип данного объекта должен реализовывать интерфейс `Fooable`. Ниже мы создаём собственный объект, и реализует для него интерфейс `Fooable`, благодаря чему можем передать его в функцию `print_foo_five_times`.

Через такие интерфейсы задаётся всё в стандартной библиотеке для стандартных коллекций, например: конструктор копирования (`Clone`), сравнение на равенство (`Eq`), получение хэша (`Hash`).

Это даёт возможность понять что от тебя требуется только по сигнатуре шаблонной функции. Что упрощает как взаимодействие со стандартной библиотекой, так и взаимодействие с библиотеками.

Такой синтаксис позволяет осуществлять не только статическую диспетчеризацию, а ещё и динамическую, то есть создать массив "указателей на объект, которые реализуют данный интерфейс", что работает через `vtable`. Пример можно посмотреть в следующем видео:

[image]

К сожалению в C++ для динамической диспетчеризации используются абстрактные классы, а для статической Концепты.

Поэтому если вы сталкиваетесь с проблемами подобными моему вопросу, советую присмотреться к языку Rust.

Comment: Так вам надо для произвольного кода проводить такой анализ или для вашего? Если для вашего, то можно изначально писать по соглашению так, что "нельзя использовать метод у объекта, если это не специфицировано в сигнатуре функции" и анализировать только `std::enable_if` или `requires` и не лезть в тело функций

Comment: Три года назад я хотел разобраться в библиотеке Anti-Grain Geometry. Поэтому спрашивал про такой инструмент. Понятно, что при написании своего нового кода лучше использовать множество best-practices для симуляции Trait'ов в C++. Лично я уже предпочту новый проект писать на Rust.

Comment: В C# тоже [думают завезти тайпклассы и внешние расширения типов](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164) (что-то наподобие трейтов Rust).